# Google Play Games leaderboard - Import highscores

Tags: android, import, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have one android game live where I implemented by own leaderboard in my own server with my own database.

No I'm going to remove that and integrate the leaderboard using Google Play Games services. The problem with this is my players will lose their existing scores...

Is there any API to import players highscores or to batch-upload highscores?

Cheers

Comment: When a player signs-in (ex. at game start-up), simply read their score from your server and then submit it to the Google Play Games leaderboard. Once you've done that, set a preference value to indicate it so you don't have to do it again for that player. You can not do this in batch since each player will have to consent to the use of the Google Play Games service upon sign-in, and some may opt-out - in which case you couldn't upload their scores anyway.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I think this is the best thing to do, as it seems clear that you need to do this from the client itself.